# Issue certificate for a PKCS#10 CSR without Cert template. 0x80094801 MS W2K3 enterprise CA

Tags: active-directory, cryptography, windows-server-2003, certificate, x509certificate

We have a MS Enterprise 2003 CA. I am trying to issue a certificate for a PKCS#10 CSR which is generated without a certificate template. I am getting the following error

> > The request contains no certificate template information. 0x80094801 (-2146875391) Denied by Policy Module 0x80094801, The request doesnot contain a certificate template extension or the Certificate template request attribute

Is there a work around to enhance interoperability of our CA so that we can issue certificates for CSR's without a certificate template?

There is a post by MS in [See HERE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910249). This is not pointing to any solution even they talk about resolution. This article discusses about some web interface. Can you please shed some light on this web interface?

Thanks

Raj

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution for my query.

**certreq** allows you to issue certificates for a PKCS#10 request without templates. Templates including custom templates can be specified according to the security policies of the Enterprise 2003 CA.

Please see below for syntax

```
certreq -submit -attrib "CertificateTemplate:<Template Name>" <CertificateRequest.req>
```

More information on this can be found at [MS technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736326(WS.10).aspx)

Thanks

Raj

Comment: Note also that you might need to **Run as Administrator** in order to process requests on the command line.